# Truncate text formatted via HTML with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

I am trying to truncate some text that has been formatted via HTML, but I need to keep the html in tact. I am doing so in SharePoint 2007 - so I am using XSLT 1.0.

I found this bit of XSLT here: http://symphony-cms.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/20816/

I was able to implement it, but it is telling me that the variable or parameter "Limit" has been defined twice.

However, the author has named many variables and parameters "Limit" and I am not sure which one I need to change.

I am fairly new to XSLT, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because at the top the XSLT the author has defined **limit** as a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="limit"/>
```

But a few lines down, then defines it as a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="limit">
```

Perhaps he had a 'buggy' xslt processor which allowed variables to be re-defined, but it should not actually be valid.

I did try renaming the variable to **newlimit** but it is hard to know whn he subsequently refers to **limit** whether it is the paramater or variable it is referring too (I couldn't actually get it to output useful HTML).

You are probably better off looking for something else to meet your needs. There may even be similar questions here on StackOverflow if you search about. For example, perhaps this meets your needs

[XSLT - Using substring with copy-of to preserve inner HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917641/xslt-using-substring-with-copy-of-to-preserve-inner-html-tags)

I am sure there may be others if you look. If not, feel free to ask a new question, giving your input HTML, and your expected output, so that it is clear what your requirements are.

Comment: Thank you for the link Tim. I had a feeling it was the first template. Unfortunately the link you supplied isn't exactly what I am looking for. I will have to ask a new question. I had done some searches, and found similar solutions;however I had no luck in modifying them to do what I need. Sadly, I am hitting up against my own knowledge barrier. Thanks again.