# Maintain HTML encoding when processing RSS XML via XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, rss, console-application, html-encode

I am developing an Windows console application that reads a XML RSS feed and translates it via an XSLT file.  One of the RSS nodes content is HMTL encoded, here is a sample below:

```
<description>&lt;b&gt;When:&lt;/b&gt; Monday, November 05, 2012 - 10:00 AM&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Where:&lt;/b&gt; Red Mountain Branch&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Where: The Roadrunner Room&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Our Job Lab is open to help you with:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Job searching&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Creating resumes and cover letters&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Completing online job applications&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Providing interview tips&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Exploring your career interests&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Improving computer skills&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Increasing workplace skills and marketability.&lt;br /&gt;&#149; Marketing through Social Media&lt;br /&gt;&#149; GETTING HIRED!&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Need more information:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Email: MesaLibJHH@gmail.com&lt;br /&gt;Twitter: @MesaLibJHH&lt;br /&gt;Facebook: www.facebook.com/MesaLibraryJobHelpHub&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</description>
```

Here is the XSLT file I am using to translate the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="category" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="rss">
          <xsl:for-each select="channel">
              <rssItems>
                  <xsl:for-each select="item">
                      <item>
                          <title>
                              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                          </title>
                          <description>
                              <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                          </description>
                          <category>
                              <xsl:for-each select="category">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>,
                              </xsl:for-each>
                          </category>
                          <link>
                              <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
                          </link>
                          <guid>
                              <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
                          </guid>
                      </item>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </rssItems>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

What modification to I need to do to the `<xsl:value-of select="description" />` to retain the HTML encoding when processing the RSS feed?

Comment: This has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp essentially you can either add extra DTD to your XSLT for the entities or you can preprocess your feed with a find and replace -&- with -&-a-m-p-;-

Comment: @LastCoder - I updated my XSLT file with the suggested solution in the linked question and it still does not maintian the original HTML encoding

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT - Using substring with copy-of to preserve inner HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917641/xslt-using-substring-with-copy-of-to-preserve-inner-html-tags)